# How can I generate a random number from a group of numbers (not a range)

Tags: c, random, numbers

I would like to be able to generate a random number from a group of numbers, like for example: 1, 2, 3, 12, 11, 23, 45, 54, 10, 10, 12, 23, 35, 24. Using the rand and the srand i can generate random numbers different each time but i would like to able to condition the outcomes by generating random numbers from a group.

Comment: You can generate random array index, and then pick the corresponding element from the array of the allowed numbers.

Comment: "different each time" - are you aware that you can generate only len(list) numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example code

Take an Array

```
int a[]={ 1, 2, 3, 12, 11, 23, 45, 54, 10, 10, 12, 23, 35, 24};
int i = rand()%14; // here 14 is number of element in array.
```

`i` will receive a value between `0` to `13`
At last

```
printf("%d",a[i]);    //print that array index
```

Comment: Isn't there a possibility the same number might be repeated?

Comment: @Gopi yes, there is possibility that same number can print more than one time. It depends upon value of `i`.

Comment: @Himanshu Thanks i'll try that. Gopi The idea is exactly that. Even though the number printed is random i can influence the outcome by repeating numbers in the group.

Comment: @Himanshu is there a way to do it without repeating the results? Turns out i may need that too. For example {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6} if i want to print 3 random random numbers they cannot be repeated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @zemanel as you are taking repetitive numbers there is many chance that you will get same number again. In example shown by me, you can take 1 more `int array` save random index it is generating if it is not previously there. And if that index number is already there generate the random number again.