# How to generate a random number from an interval like [0-5] U [8-12] in c

Tags: c

i want to generate a random number from [0-5] U [8-12]
normaly when i want to generate a number from [0-5] i would simply write x=rand()%6 , but as you see
i want to generate x from an union of 2 intervals
thanks

Comment: What you "would normally do" is probably not statistically correct, either.

Comment: what can i do instead ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927978/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-from-a-group-of-numbers-not-a-range/

Comment: It depends what you expect. If you want a particular kind of statistical distribution, like "uniform", then you have to implement one.

Answer (score 4):

1. Generate a random number `i` in the range [0, 11).*
2. Define `const unsigned int a[11] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };`
3. Return `a[i]`.

<sub>*) This is probably a lot harder than you think, depending on what you think you're achieving.</sub>

Comment: And see section 13 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), starting with question 13.15, for some tips on random numbers. (It doesn't address this particular question.)

Comment: that would work fine for this example ,but what if i have an in terval like this : [0-200]U[320-500]U[533-620]... ??

Comment: @ItachiKurosaki: Same idea, generate a random index ... then just a few more conditionals, or you could have a lookup table for array pointers and index offsets.

Comment: @ItachiKurosaki You can also alloc the array in this example, doesnt have to be a define. In this way you can modify possible answers on the fly